# How to read and split csv files in a smart way?

Tags: python, csv, split

I've got a problem with reading csv and splitting it. I want to read a csv file of which all the rows look something like this:

one,two,three,"[four, five, six]"

I want to read it line by line and split the entries apart. Unfortunately, the **"** and **[** make it quite complicated for me. So far my reader splits whenever it sees a comma, but then I get things like **"[four**, whereas actually I would like to remove the **"** and the **[** (and respectively the **]** and the **"** at the end). So the result I would like to get should look something like:

[one, two, three, four, five, six]

So far I know I can do that by splitting and then cutting the first (or the last letters of the specific elements of that row. But I was wondering if there was some clever trick or idea, that doesn't look so clumsy.

Comment: post your problematic code.

Comment: You couls set the separator to " that way youd have 3 columns (last one empty). And split the first and second columns to get the result. Alternatively you could parse and remove the brakets and quotation marks from the file before loading it as a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution using regular expressions:

```
import re

row = 'one,two,three,"[four, five, six]"'
words = [re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", '', word) for word in row.split(",")]

print(words)
```

If you don't want to use the "re" package, then you can use the "replace" function. For example:

```
row = 'one,two,three,"[four, five, six]"'
words = [word.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "").replace(' ', "") for word in row.split(",")]

print(words)
```

Of course, there are many ways to do what you requested, but these two are the first ones that came to mind.

EDIT:

Since the CSV returns a list, not a string, this is what I came up with. Mind you, there are probably better ways to do this, but it does work.

```
import csv
import re

with open('testData.csv') as csvfile:
    linereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in linereader:
        wordsToSplit = ','.join([(element if len(element.split(',')) == 1 else ','.join([re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", '', e) for e in element.split(',')])) for element in row])
        words = wordsToSplit.split(',')
        print(words)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Quick question, probably a dumb one but I'm pretty new to python: When I read the CSV file with the normal CSV reader, I get a list and not a string. So I actually cannot split this list. Can I read the CSV file directly as a string or do I have to convert the list into a string first?

Comment: I forgot that the CSV reader returns a list, sorry about that. I edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure yet, whether I will take your idea or the one from Leonis, but I guess both will do the trick. So thank you for your extensive help!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you have tried to parse your CSV file on your own. Using the Python csv module is much simpler, and I recommend using that method instead.

Code example to print all rows of a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile: # opens the file
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)    # reads the file
    for row in csvreader:              # prints rows
        print(row)

# output for your values: ['one', 'two', 'three', '[four, five, six]']
```

Using similar code to get a list of each row, you could then parse the final string value representing the other three values, '[four, five, six]'. The code to parse that string might look something like this:

```
initialString = '[four, five, six]'
list = initialString.strip('][').split(', ')
# result is ['four', 'five', 'six']
```

Finally, you could concatenate the two lists to form one larger list:

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['four', 'five', 'six']
finallist = list1 + list2
# finallist is ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

**EDIT:** Full Code Example using above method:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:         
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)           
    for row in csvreader:                      
        result = [row[0], row[1], row[2]] + row[3].strip('][').split(', ')
        print(result)

# result is a list ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Say you wanted the result to be like that list, but a string with square brackets on both sides. Then the easiest way I can think of to do that with the above code, would be:

```
resultStr = '['
for number in result:
    resultStr = resultStr + number + ', '

resultStr.strip()
resultStr = resultStr + ']'
# resultStr = '[one, two, three, four, five, six]'
```

Keep in mind you'd have to put this in the for loop of the full code example above to print each full row of data in this format.

**Explanation:**
How does the below work?

result = [row[0], row[1], row[2]] + row[3].strip('][').split(', ')

First, it takes the first 3 values of the split list, 'one', 'two', and 'three', and makes a list with those 3 values (the extra square brackets). Then, it combines this list with another one created by splitting the fourth value to form a complete list, ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

Hope this edited answer explains a way of solving this problem

Comment: actually I did use the CSV module. But I did not know one can concatenate strip and split the way you did there, so this would be a fitting solution as well. Thank you!

Comment: @T-Man I edited this answer to give a full code example of how to solve the problem my way. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Yes! This helps a lot. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I already commented below the solution from Stefan, but it looked kinda messy there with the code, so here I got it again. This is what I would have with Stefan's solution. The csv reader gets me a list and not a string and the list cannot be split. So can I read the file as a string or do I need to convert it?

```
import re

with open('testData.csv') as csvfile:
    linereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in linereader:
        words = [re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", '', word) for word in row.split(",")]
        print(words)
```